# how to send parameters to main function in objective c

Tags: objective-c, program-entry-point

I don't know how to pass parameters to main(int argc, char * argv[]) function in objective c. using xcode. Please help me.

Comment: Are you building a command-line utility?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know how to do that as I didn't do it before just curious to know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, edit the scheme for your target. Then click on the "Arguments" tab. This will reveal the arguments editor where you can set the arguments that are sent to your target when running from Xcode.

However, if you are building a command-line utility and already have it built and are running it outside of Xcode, then you'll need to pass the arguments via the command-line as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The main function's parameters are the program arguments passed by the system when the program is executed. For example, when the program is run from the command line, the arguments will be the parts of the command line (e.g. if you executed `./yourapp -t "some text"`, argc would be 3 and argv would be `{"./yourapp", "-t", "some text"}`).